# ERROR: Django connect to PostgreSQL via Docker

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

My code from **settings.py**

```
   DATABASES = {
         'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
         'NAME': 'postgres',
         'USER': 'postgres',
         'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
         'HOST': 'db',
         'PORT': 5432
         }
   }
```

*Dockerfile*

```
   # Pull base image
   FROM python:3.8
   # Set environment variables
   ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
   ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
   # Set work directory
   WORKDIR /code
   # Install dependencies
   COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
   RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system
   # Copy project
   COPY . /code/
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
  version: '3.8'
  services:
   web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
   db:
    image: postgres:11
```

when docker-compose logs on cmd, I see an error

```
  db_1   | Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
  db_1   |        You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
  db_1   |        superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".
  db_1   |
  db_1   |        You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
  db_1   |        connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.
  db_1   |
  db_1   |        See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
  db_1   |        https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
```

If I use basic **settings.py** with sqlite3 It works and connecting to the server

So I am a new one on Docker, How to solve it?
Thanks for your answer

It is done to me

**docker-compose.yml(Edited)**

```
  version: '3.8'
  services:
   web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
     - .:/code
    ports:
     - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
     - db
   db:
    image: postgres:11
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  volumes:
   postgres_data:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Init your postgres container with environment variables:

```
  db:
      image: postgres:11
      environment:
          - POSTGRES_USER=example
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=example
          - POSTGRES_DB=example
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the password for `PostgreSQL` using the environment variable `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`.

If you want to disable the password requirement you can do it by replacing the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD : [your_password]` with `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust`.

```
job:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/postgres:9.6
        environment:
          #...
          POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
          #...
```

Comment: Can you replace these images with actual text, that the original questioner can copy and paste?

Comment: Actually stack overflow is not give indentation to this

Comment: I am trying to do this however the first answer is worked for me